# Knockout JS Not Binding To Variables

Tags: javascript, laravel, input, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm creating a Laravel application that uses Knockout JS, and cannot get the *"data-bind"* property within form input variables to work. The form has two parts with the right side having a list of entries with an edit link, and the left side contains the fields where the editing is undertaken.

The edit link will correctly populate the edit fields, and changes to the list and DB is successful.

But my intent is if the child record id is included in the URL as well as the parent id. Then populate the edit fields with the selected entry on loading. No errors are appearing in the browser console.

I'm new to Laravel and very new to Knockout JS. Any idea as to the cause of my issue?

Page JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var stepsOb = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({!! $show['steps'] !!}));
  var steps = $.isPlainObject(stepsOb) ? [] : stepsOb;
  @if (!empty($show['selectedStep']))
    var editStepsOb = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({!! $show['selectedStep'] !!}));
    var editStep = $.isPlainObject(editStepsOb) ? [] : editStepsOb;
    var planning = new Planning({
        steps: steps,
        completed: {{ $show['goal']['completed'] ? 'true' : '0' }},
        id: {{ $show['goal']['goal_id'] }},
        newPlan:  @if (isset($show['steps']) and count($show['steps']) == 0) true @else false @endif,
        currentStep: {{ $show['selectedStep']->id }},
        currentDescription: '{{ $show['selectedStep']->description }}',
        currentWhen: '{{ $show['selectedStep']->do_it_when }}',
        currentDate: '{{ $show['selectedStep']->date }}',
        isNew: false
    });
  @else
    var planning = new Planning({
        steps: steps,
        completed: {{ $show['goal']['completed'] ? 'true' : '0' }},
        id: {{ $show['goal']['goal_id'] }},
        newPlan:  @if (isset($show['steps']) and count($show['steps']) == 0) true @else false @endif
    });
  @endif
  ko.applyBindings(planning);   
});
</script>
```

Page onload view model data showing the population of the "current" elements
[page onload view model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTD8n.jpg).
Post KO binding view model data showing the population of the "current" elements [post ko binding view model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn7qE.jpg).

The applicable Laravel Blade code containing the elements to be populated is below.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="id" />                    
<div role="tabpanel" class="tabpanel-plan">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#iwill" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="iwill">
      <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: currentDescription" name="description" class="form-control" data-bv-notempty="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                            
<div role="tabpanel" class="tabpanel-plan" id="willdoit">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: showDate() }"><a href="#doiton" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
    <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { active: showWhen() }"><a href="#everytime" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">I will do this every...</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" data-bind="css: { active: showDate() }" id="doiton">
      <div class="has-feedback">
        <div class="date">
          <input data-bind="pickadate: currentDate" type="text" name="date" id="date" data-bv-date="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Select a date" data-bv-field="when" />
        </div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" data-bind="css: { active: showWhen() }" id="everytime">
    <input type="text" name="when" data-bind="textInput: currentWhen" placeholder="Enter when you're going to do it" class="form-control" data-bv-field="when" />
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I discover my issue which was a function within a separate JS file that was overwriting the view model values.